# undefined method `updated_at' for #<MatchResult::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000232e608> in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have two active record array. I merged these two arrays and now I want to sort them according to "updated_at" field.

```
@notification_challenges=Challenge.where("to_id=? and activity_id=?" ,current_user.id,@activity.id)
@match_results=[]
@notification_challenges.each do |k|
@match_results=@match_results<<MatchResult.where("challenge_id=? and result_confirmation_status=?" ,k.id,1)
end

if !@match_results.blank?
  @notifications=@notifications+@match_results
end

if !@notification_challenges.blank?
        @notifications=@notifications+@notification_challenges
end

if !@notifications.blank?
      @notifications2=(@notifications).sort_by(&:updated_at)
      @notifications2=@notifications.reverse
end
```

but it is giving following error :

```
undefined method `updated_at' for #<MatchResult::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000232e608>
```

and

```
@notifications=(@match_results+@notification_challenges).sort_by(&:updated_at)
```

is working fine.
But I want to check that @match_results or @notification_challenges is blank or not so I am merging these two arrays and then applying "sort_by" functions.

Comment: Use this code  `@notifications2=(@notifications).sort_by{|e| e[:updated_at]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MatchResult` in your case probably returns an `MatchResult` object with an array of records in it, so when you add `MatchResult` to your first array you'll end up having something like:

`[a, b, c, MatchResult[d, e, f]]`

where the 4th element in this array is the `MatchResult` object that does not have `update_at` attribute or method.

You could try to loop through the results in `MatchResult` and push each one into first array:

```
results = MatchResult.where("challenge_id=? and result_confirmation_status=?" ,k.id,1)
@match_results = results.map{|c| @match_results << c}
```

Just an idea, cause I am not sure what `MatchResult` returns in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
MatchResult.where("challenge_id=? and result_confirmation_status=?" ,k.id,1)
```

already returns an array(Frankly speaking an ActiveRecord::Relation). So, should not push. You should be adding.

And I feel it is better to initialize @notification_challenges to an empty array too. Just in case...

```
@notification_challenges=[]
@notification_challenges=Challenge.where("to_id=? and activity_id=?" ,current_user.id,@activity.id)
@match_results=[]
@notification_challenges.each do |k|
@match_results=@match_results + MatchResult.where("challenge_id=? and result_confirmation_status=?" ,k.id,1)
end
```